# Why does CodeChef give NZEC EOFError: EOF when reading a line for input() on python3.6

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-3.6

The following code runs fine on PyCharm but the CodeChef IDE simply won't take it. Am I missing something here? Please convince me I'm a fool for sitting on this all day

I even tried switching to Python 2.7 and changing the functions to raw_input().

```
n = int(input()) # Line 1. This is where it goes bananas
```

I get the desired Output on PyCharm

But, on CodeChef:

```
Runtime Error: NZEC
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: CodeChef problem Link?

Answer (score 1):

Focus on `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

It happens because the code needs an input from command line, but the file that provides the input is empty.

```
n =int(input())
```

consider the above line. It'll expect an input but it will get EOF delimiter as soon as it reads the file.

Hence, raising an EOFError.

Answer (score 0):

Insist of using `input()` method to take input from user you can use `stdin`(standard input).

Simply `import sys.stdin` and use `n=eval(stdin.readline())` to take input. Also put your code inside try and `execpt EOFError`.

Sample -

```
from sys import stdin
try:
    n=eval(stdin.readline())
    # write your code here
except EOFError:
    print("EOFError")
```