# Why is there an EOF error for simply assigning n = int(input()), when the input is an integer?

Tags: python, input

I am writing code for a coding contest on CodeChef, but am having issues with processing the `input()`'s. Here is the question I am solving (P.S. I am not asking for any solutions):

https://www.codechef.com/SEPT21C/problems/AIRLINE

And here is my code:

```
n = int(input())
res = []

for testers in range(n):
    res.append(list(map(int,input().split(" "))))

for i in res:
    if (i[1]+i[2]<= i[3] and i[0]<= i[4]) or (i[0]+i[2]<= i[3] and i[1]<= i[4]) or (i[1]+i[0]<= i[3] and i[2]<= i[4]):
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

I am getting an `'NZEC' runtime error` and `"EOFError: EOF when reading a line"` for line 1. While I understand the EOF error, I don't see why this is the case for line 1?? I've watched a few YouTube videos on this, and they seem to process the input in this manner too. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: For which input you got runtime error?

Comment: I believe it is the first line- as it says line 1.

Comment: Do I need to save it as a file then attach do you think?

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138609/why-does-codechef-give-nzec-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line-for-input-on-pyt). It could be that you are attempting to *run* your code instead of submitting it.

Comment: Works for me. I wonder how you're executing this

Comment: Thanks guys, @quamrana, you are right. It is because I was trying to run it rather than submit it! And the links is very helpful, I now see using input() in my code won't work when running it on the CodeChef compiler :)